# Upgrade Ubuntu MATE from 20.04 to 22.04 crashed

Tags: upgrade, crash, mate, ubuntu-mate

While performing the upgrade using the GUI, the computer crashed and the screen froze. It's an old computer with a LED that lights up when there is activity on the disk, but there was none. So I concluded that the whole system had crashed and not just the screen and restarted the computer using the reset button.

Luckily, the system restarted alright, but now it's not offering me to continue the upgrade. The update manager is suggesting that I need to do a partial upgrade, but it's unclear to me what that means and whether I will end up with a properly upgraded system.

Is there a way to clean up and restart the upgrade, preferably in a way that doesn't clear the packages that were already downloaded? (It crashed while downloading packages.)

Or even better, is there a way to simply continue the upgrade?

In general, any advice on how to proceed is welcome.

Comment: If the system is offering you a "partial upgrade," then there are two possibilities: Your system was already broken before you began the release-upgrade, or your system was  indeed installing packages when it was killed. But that does not matter: Offer of a "partial upgrade" means that your system is seriously broken *now*. Partial upgrades rarely end well, but perhaps you will be the exception. Advice: Boot from a LiveUSB, backup your data, and then clean-install Ubuntu. Recovering from a broken upgrade requires skill, experience, and time -- reinstalling is easier and faster.

Comment: @user535733 I did the partial upgrade and the graphical UI fails to launch now. I can log in using ctrl+alt+f1(-f6) and the printer connected to it is available on the network. It's primarily used to make the printer available on the network and since that is working, I feel more inclined to try to repair the GUI functionality than re-installing it. Any idea where to start and what logs to look at to figure out what is wrong? I suppose another option would be to uninstall all the GUI stuff, if it's not working anyway. Not sure how to do that either though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after several hours, the system is working as expected again. As you might have read in my comment I did the partial upgrade and after rebooting, there was no GUI to log in. There was just a blinking underscore. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, I could log in to the console.

I ran `startx` and got an error message that I could Google. Based on that I ran `lshw -c display` and found out that my display device was "UNCLAIMED". It also gave me information about the device that I could Google to find out what drivers it needs. I installed the drivers suggested by Google and then it started working again.

I had a few more problems though. There was a popup about a system error every time I logged in, which I Googled and found out that I could fix by deleting the crash logs in `/var/crash/` Three things had crashed, X.org, the upgrade and Pulse, so I figured I should check if the audio was working. It wasn't. I tried a few things and I'm not sure what exactly fixed it, but one of the things I did was delete the configuration in `~/.config/pulse/` and rebooted to have it rebuilt. It didn't immediately fix the issue, so I continued messing around with connecting and disconnecting headphones and eventually, all the correct options started to appear in the sound settings and the audio was working as expected.

Everything seems to be working fine now. While the problems I had may be unique to my particular system, at least there is hope that you can recover your system after a crashed upgrade, like I did. It may not be as broken as it first seems, and there's not much risk in trying, as the option of reinstalling is always there.